# How to extract a substring from string using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

code
I want regex for this format and filter out 123456 if match the current format

```
PO # 123456
PO# 123456
PO #123456
P.O. # 123456
P.O.# 123456
P.O. #123456
```

We have to filter substring from string notes__c field. my regex is only working for `PO #123456` and  `P.O. #123456`

```
    Matcher rm = r.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile('PO #(\\S+)\\s');
    if(rm.find()) {
    string res2 =  rm.group(1);
    oOrder.test__c = res2;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Java?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to note here are the optional whitespace. Whitespace can appear before and/or after the `#`. Whenever you see a pattern like this, you usually need `\s*` (if you allow multiple whitespace) or `\s?` (if you only allow one or more whitespace).

The first part can either be `PO` or `P.O.`. We can write these two alternatives with the `|` token. Remember to escape the `.`s.

The whole regex looks like this:

```
(?:PO|P\.O\.)\s*#\s*(\d+)
```

Here, I assumed the thing you want to capture matches `\d+`. If that part can contain letters, change the capture group accordingly.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMTZPp/1)

To write the regex as a string literal, you need to escape the backslashes:

```
(?:PO|P\\.O\\.)\\s*#\\s*(\\d+)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this error comes-
Compile Error: Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '(?:PO|P\.O\.)\s*#\s*(\d+)'. Illegal character sequence \.' in string literal.

Comment: @brijendersinghrathore See the edit. What language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this error comes- Compile Error: Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '(?:PO|P\.O\.)\s*#\s*(\d+)'. Illegal character sequence \.' in string literal. –

Comment: @brijendersinghrathore did you try escaping the backslashes? Also, if you are using Java, you should use `"` to delimit a string literal, not `'`. This is why knowing what language you are using is important.

Comment: I am using it in salesforce in a trigger.notes__c field value can be anything suppose it is "Product: Multi Screen Encoder Version: 3.51.10 (008) Order Number: 0030000a9Ddy                                                   PO # 129999 Comment: some comments" now first i have to verify whether PO # 129999 exist is in notes__c then filter out 129999 and update it into test__c

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.?(\d+)$
```

For the example you posted it works.

https://regex101.com/r/eTjbMo/1/

Comment: I think my question is not clear.As an example i am posting a notes__c field value it is
"Product: Multi Screen Encoder Version: 3.51.10 (008) Order Number: 0030000a9Ddy PO # 129999 Comment: some comments"
now first  i have to verify whether PO # 129999 exist is in notes__c  then filter out 129999 and update it into test__c

Comment: Can you update the question then? Although my solution does not solve your problem, for someone just coming here, my answer does work as intended, and thus changing it would be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Above codes are not working friends

i HAVE MODIFIED MY CODE TO

```
if(oOrder.Notes__c != null) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile('PO # (\\S+)\\s');
        Pattern q = Pattern.compile('PO# (\\S+)\\s');
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile('PO #(\\S+)\\s');
        Pattern s = Pattern.compile('P.O. # (\\S+)\\s');
        Pattern t = Pattern.compile('P.O.# (\\S+)\\s');
        Pattern u = Pattern.compile('P.O. #(\\S+)\\s');
        Matcher pm = p.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
        Matcher qm = q.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
        Matcher rm = r.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
        Matcher sm = s.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
        Matcher tm = t.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);
        Matcher um = u.matcher(oOrder.Notes__c);

        system.debug('find = ' +pm.find()); 
        if (pm.find()){
          string res =  pm.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res;
        } 
        if(qm.find()){
          string res1 =  qm.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res1;
        }
        if(rm.find()){
          string res2 =  rm.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res2;
        }
        if(sm.find()){
          string res3 =  sm.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res3;
        }
        if(tm.find()){
          string res4 =  tm.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res4;
        }
        if(um.find()){
          string res5 =  um.group(1);
          oOrder.test__c = res5;
        }
      }
```

it is covering everything except First one
PO # 123456